# Reforming $\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}x)+\sin(\frac{x}{2})\sin((n+1)x)$ to $\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}x)\sin(\frac{n+2}{2}x)$

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to reform

$\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}x)+\sin(\frac{x}{2})\sin((n+1)x)$

to

$\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}x)\sin(\frac{n+2}{2}x)$

but I just don't know what to do. There probably are a few tricks to use that I don't know.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing it is some product-to-sum formula.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sin\dfrac{n+2}2x\sin\dfrac{n+1}2x-\sin\dfrac n2x\sin\dfrac{n+1}2x$$

$$=\sin\dfrac{n+1}2x\left(\sin\dfrac{n+2}2x-\sin\dfrac n2x\right)$$

Use [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula $\sin C-\sin D$ and $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$